# unity's new input system - generic parameter passthrough

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am writing an semi generic wrapper for unity's new input system.

> ```
> using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
>     
> public class NewInputSystemWrapper
> {
>   public void test<T>() where T : notnull
>   {
>     InputAction action = Whatever();
>     _ = action.ReadValue<T>();
>   }
> }
> ```

I am getting the following error message. But why? I have declared that T is notnull. (I just want to pass through T to the ReadValue method.)
[image]

Comment: Could you provide your full code? `Whatever` and `ReadValue<T>()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow the constraint of [ReadValue](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.3/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputAction.html#UnityEngine_InputSystem_InputAction_ReadValue__1) method.

```
public void test<T>() where T : struct
```

Comment: Worked :D. But why does it say that it needs to be notnull and not a struct? Wouldn't struct exclude primatives?

Comment: It says "non-nullable value type".